# ActiveRecord model without primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a ActiveRecord model `GPA` that doesn't have a primary key:

```
class GPA < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

When I try to call `GPA.first.to_json` I get `TypeError: false is not a symbol`. I'm guessing that this is due to ActiveRecord trying to lookup the primary key. What is the correct way to implement a model without a primary key?

[image]

Comment: what does GPA.first gives you?

Comment: `GPA.first` gives me `#<GPA strm: 1120, gpa: "1.3", acad_career: nil, student_id: 13798578>` but calling `to_json` on it throws the error I've indicated above

Comment: For what I've tested this seems to be a bug. If you do `GPA.first.attributes` you will get something like `{"name"=>"1", "count1"=>1, nil=>nil}` and this `nil=>nil` is what's causing the problem. In your case you might have `false=>false` instead.

Comment: try to set set_primary_key "student_id" in your GPA model

Comment: `student_id` is not a unique column. Setting this might have unforeseen side effects.

Comment: how about putting `attr_accessor :id` in your model? It would override the defaults and give you nil for id always. But id is not in db so does not matter.

Answer (score 20):

Normally there is either some column or combination of columns which together do form a primary key.  When you say your table doesn't have a primary key do you mean it doesn't have an `id` field?

Is there another column that is a unique/natural key? If so you can do:

```
class GPA < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :strm    # eg column strm is a unique/natural key
end
```

You can also use composite keys with the [composite keys gem](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys), as follows:

```
class GPA < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_keys :student_id, :strm
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this on your migrations or schema

```
create_table :gpas, :id => false do |t|
  t.int :strm
  t.string :gpa
  t.string :acad_career
  t.int :student_id
end
```

Comment: I *don't* have control over the table. The table has has already been created (it already contains the fields you've listed anyways).

Answer (score 2):

It is highly advisable to use the rails default conventions when modelling your data. Only override defaults if you are dealing with legacy tables.

### Option 1

You have to override the primary key for your model by doing the following:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = "strm"
end
```

Now if you call `.to_json` the json will include the key `id` instead of `strm`.

### Option 2

Alternative is to use a json constructors such as [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder), so it does not try to convert non-existent 'id' to json using default Rails json constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Add a migration that adds id as a column. It's not going to hurt any existing code. Just make sure it's got an autoincrement on it so it's not going to moan about duplicate entry 0.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html)?