# unexpected attributes found in Active Record object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am finding an unexpected attribute in an ActiveRecord object and I can't figure out where its coming from. Note the final attribute `nil => nil`.

```
irb(main):001:0> p = ProgExit.new
=> #<ProgExit id: nil, Student_Bnum: nil, Program_ProgCode: nil, ExitCode_ExitCode: nil, ExitTerm: nil, ExitDate: nil, GPA: nil, GPA_last60: nil, RecommendDate: nil, Details: nil>
irb(main):002:0> p.attributes
=> {"id"=>nil, "Student_Bnum"=>nil, "Program_ProgCode"=>nil, "ExitCode_ExitCode"=>nil, "ExitTerm"=>nil, "ExitDate"=>nil, "GPA"=>nil, "GPA_last60"=>nil, "RecommendDate"=>nil, "Details"=>nil, nil=>nil}
```

Two other items of note: 1) this problem doesn't present for any other models. 2) this problem is the same for this model across development, test and production. 3) The model does not use attr_accessor anywhere.

Any idea where this comes from? I am including the related model though it is thus far tiny (still working on it).

```
class ProgExit < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :student, foreign_key: "Student_Bnum"
    belongs_to :program, foreign_key: "Program_ProgCode"
    belongs_to :exit_code, foreign_key: "ExitCode_ExitCode"
end
```

And here is the relevant code from my schema.rb

```
  create_table "prog_exits", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "id",                           null: false
    t.string   "Student_Bnum",      limit: 9,  null: false
    t.string   "Program_ProgCode",  limit: 45, null: false
    t.string   "ExitCode_ExitCode", limit: 45, null: false
    t.integer  "ExitTerm",                     null: false
    t.datetime "ExitDate"
    t.float    "GPA",               limit: 24
    t.float    "GPA_last60",        limit: 24
    t.datetime "RecommendDate"
    t.text     "Details"
  end

  add_index "prog_exits", ["ExitCode_ExitCode"], name: "fk_Exit_ExitCode1_idx", using: :btree
  add_index "prog_exits", ["Program_ProgCode"], name: "fk_Exit__Program_idx", using: :btree
  add_index "prog_exits", ["Student_Bnum"], name: "fk_Exit_Student1_idx", using: :btree
  add_index "prog_exits", ["id"], name: "id", using: :btree
```

I'm not sure what other code to include here but if there is something else that might be the culprit I can share that to.

Comment: from your current `schema.rb` can you post ProgExit schema?

Comment: relevant code from schema.rb added above.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this on a rails '4.2.3' app with mysql with no luck! getting the correct attributes list without the `nil=>nil` part!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you've overriden the default primary key for this table (by including the `id: false` option in the `create_table` statement), you need to explicitly define a primary key for this model.

Per [Rails docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table), you can use `self.primary_key=` on the model to define the key explicitly.

see related issue: [ActiveRecord model without primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923477/activerecord-model-without-primary-key)

Comment: I found this ruby gem to address my problem perfectly https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys.